# Partitioning $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ via the class group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a number field.  There is a surjective map $\phi:\mathbb{P}^1(K)\to Cl(K)$ from the field to the class group, sending $[\alpha:\beta]$ to the class of the ideal $(\alpha,\beta)$.  What does the fibre over an ideal class ``look like''?

I'm specifically interested in $K$ imaginary quadratic and whether or not there are circles in each of the fibres.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}\cap K$ is contained in the fibre over the principal class.

Are there any elementary observations to make concerning $\phi$?  Or references?  Thanks.

Here are some pictures for reference, the two classes in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$

http://math.colorado.edu/~rohi1040/randomshare/sqrt5princlass.pdf

http://math.colorado.edu/~rohi1040/randomshare/sqrt5otherclass.pdf

===================================================================

As noted in one of the answers below, $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ as fractional linear transformations and the fibres of $\phi$ are the $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$-orbits.  So, for instance, $\phi^{-1}(1)\cong SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)/Stab(\infty)$.  However, I don't think the fibres are isomorphic, and I don't know how to pick out the conjugacy classes of point-stabilizers (maximal elementary parabolic subgroups of $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$?).

Answer (score 4):

The fibers are precisely the orbits of the natural action of $SL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$. See [this note by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/SL2classno.pdf) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's why I'm interested in them (and how I made the pictures above).  I'm looking for geodesic surfaces in the Bianchi orbifolds ($H^3/PSL_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$, $K$ imaginary quadratic) that live in one cusp (or in subsets of the cusps, etc.)